# Is there a way to set a distinct ID and name for a text_field in Rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord

I've got a Rails 2 site I'm trying to add a form handler to, but I'm running into problems converting the html form fields into form handler fields.

The form code begins with:

```
    <% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
```

I keep getting errors when I try things like

```
    <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :html=>{ :value => 'New Map', :name=>'newsavedmapname', :id=> 'savedmap_name', :size => '30' } %>
```

Error:

```
    ActionView::TemplateError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)) on line #284 of app/views/layouts/maptry.html.erb:
```

Here are the fields. How can I convert these to form handler fields in Rails 2?

```
    <input id="savemap_name" name="newsavedmapname" size="30" type="text" value="New Map"></p>

    <select id="startdrop" name="startthere">
    <OPTIONS HERE>
    </select>

    <select multiple id="waypoints" class="mobile-waypoints-remove" name="waypointsselected[]">
    <OPTIONS HERE>
    </select>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

**Edit 1 Error Code for the Text_Field**

Using Bigxiang's approach, I get

```
    Processing NewsavedmapsController#create (for IP at Date Time) [POST]
    Parameters: {"endhere"=>"", "endthere"=>"SAMPLE ADDRESS 1", "newsavedmap"=>{"newsavedmapname"=>"test Map"}, "startthere"=>"SAMPLE ADDRESS 2", "starthere"=>"", "optimize"=>"on"}

    ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: newsavedmapname)
```

The line with "newsavedmap"=>{"newsavedmapname"=>"test Map"} should just read

```
    "newsavedmapname"=>"test Map"
```

How can I do this? My controller starts with:

```
    def create

    @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new(params[:newsavedmap])
    @newsavedmap.name = params[:newsavedmapname]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :newsavedmapname :id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30, :value=>"New Map"%>
  <%= f.select :startthere, YOUR_COLLECTIONS, {}, {:id=>"startdrop"}%>
  <%= f.select :waypointsselected, YOUR_COLLECTIONS, {}, {:id=>"waypoints", :class=>"mobile-waypoints-remove", :multiple => true}%>
<% end %>
```

make sure YOUR_COLLECTIONS should be an array like ['a', 'b', 'c'] or [['name1', id1],['name2', id2],['name3', id3]].

If you persist the parameter is "newsavedmapname"=>"test Map", try this:

```
<% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :newsavedmapname, "New Map", :id=>"savemap_name", :size=>30%>
  <%= select_tag :startthere, options_for_select(YOUR_COLLECTIONS), {:id=>"startdrop"}%>
  <%= select_tag :waypointsselected, options_for_select(YOUR_COLLECTIONS), {:id=>"waypoints", :class=>"mobile-waypoints-remove", :multiple => true}%>
<% end %>
```

But I don't understand why not use parameter's name as same as the column's name. For example, I see your newsavedmap model has a column named "name". you can use it directly

```
<% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name , :value=>"New Map" %>
<% end %>
```

in your controller , you can delete line @newsavedmap.name = params[:newsavedmapname]

```
def create

  @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new(params[:newsavedmap])

  if @newsavedmap.save
    #######
  end
end
```

Comment: Bigxiang, I'm still running into errors. Please see above. Also, your text_field code may be missing a comma after :newsavedmapname . I added the comma in my version of the code.